# RabbitMQ with AMQP PHP extension , Queue returning 3 items only

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ and am stuck on this weird issue. This is my consumer code:

```
<?php
    function processMessage($envelope, $queue) 
    {
        echo $envelope->getBody() . "\n";
    }
    $routing_key = 'newTest.txt';
    $exchange_name = 'newTest.msg';
    $connection = new AMQPConnection();
    if ($connection->connect()) {
        echo "Established a connection to the broker\n";
        $ch = new AMQPChannel($connection);
        $queue = new AMQPQueue($ch);
        $queue->declare();
        try{
            if($queue->bind($exchange_name,$routing_key))
            {
                $queue->consume("processMessage");  
            }
            else
                echo "Could Not Bind";
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Cannot connect to the broker";
    }
?>
```

I am publishing from the command line with:

```
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=newTest.msg routing_key=newTest.txt payload='HELLO';
```

When the consumer is running if i run the command line publish multiple times the output from the queue stops after 3 items. Any idea whats going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [acknowledge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpqueue.ack.php) or [reject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpqueue.nack.php) message in consumer.

```
function processMessage($envelope, $queue) 
{
    echo $envelope->getBody() . "\n";
    $queue->ack($envelope->getDeliveryTag());
}
```

Also you can use AMQP_AUTOACK to automatically acknowledge all income messages.

```
            $queue->consume("processMessage", AMQP_AUTOACK);
```

By default [prefetch count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/amqpchannel.setprefetchcount.php) on channel is 3, so you receive 3 messages and then broker waits for client to ack or reject messages.

P.S.: alternativly, you can look into my [demo sources](https://github.com/pinepain/amqpy/tree/master/demo/canonical) for consumer and producer example in php.